# i deleted the arrow pointing to the view in Xcode. how do i get it back

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I deleted the little arrow that points to the view in Xcode. How do I get it back. There is always an arrow that points to which view your app is supposed to load up on. I accidentally deleted that arrow. Now whenever i run my app it just goes to a blank screen. How do I get the arrow back?

Answer (score 4):

1) Select the desired View Controller from Storyboard

2) From Left Pane, go to **Attribute Inspector**

3) Check "Is Initial View Controller"

For your convenience, I attached the screenshot too.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Select view controller that you would like to the make initial one
2. Select checkbox "is intital View Controller"

   [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCcKO.png)